# Fluent Nhibernate map list of lists

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am writing mapping for the class with Fluent Nhibernate:

```
public class UniqueFeaturesSet : IEntity
    {
        public UniqueFeaturesSet(List<List<double>> mfcc)
        {
            MFCC = mfcc;
        }

        public virtual List<List<double>> MFCC { get; set; }

        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

How to map `List<List<double>>` ?

Comment: No idea why this gets down-voted. It's probably a duplicate, I have this question already answered somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to map nested collections with [Fluent][N]Hibernate. The inner collection needs to be in an own class.